# Area / NIntegrate over a Region fails depending on variable name

Tags: numerical-integration, regions

I'm trying to plot how the `Area` of an `ImplicitRegion` defined by four (ugly) inequalities depends on parameters.  It seems I need to `Simplify` first.

```
a12 = \[Rho]/A; a13 = A \[Rho];
a21 = A \[Rho]; a23 = \[Rho]/A;
a31 = \[Rho]/A; a32 = A \[Rho];

ineq = Simplify[
  -((r1 - r2 a12 - r3 a13 + r3 a12 a23 + r2 a13 a32 - r1 a23 a32)/(-1 + a12 a21 + a13 a31 - a12 a23 a31 - a13 a21 a32 + a23 a32)) > 0 && 
  -((-r2 + r1 a21 - r3 a13 a21 + r3 a23 + r2 a13 a31 - r1 a23 a31)/(1 - a12 a21 - a13 a31 + a12 a23 a31 + a13 a21 a32 - a23 a32)) > 0 &&
  -((-r3 + r3 a12 a21 + r1 a31 - r2 a12 a31 + r2 a32 - r1 a21 a32)/(1 - a12 a21 - a13 a31 + a12 a23 a31 + a13 a21 a32 - a23 a32)) > 0 &&
  (-((-r3 (-1 + a12 a21 - a13 a21 + a23) + r1 (-1 + a23) a31 + r2 (1 + a12 a31 - a13 a31 - a32) + r1 a21 (-1 + a32)) (-a23 (r2 - r1 a21 + r3 a13 a21 - r3 a23 - r2 a13 a31 + r1 a23 a31) a32 (r3 - r3 a12 a21 - r1 a31 + r2 a12 a31 - r2 a32 + r1 a21 a32) + (r3 a13 (-1 + a21) + r3 (-1 + a12) a23 - r2 (-1 + a12 + a13 a31 - a13 a32) - r1 (-1 + a21 - a23 a31 + a23 a32)) (-r3 (-1 + a13 + a12 a21 - a12 a23) + r2 a12 (-1 + a31) + r2 (-1 + a13) a32 - r1 (-1 + a31 - a21 a32 + a23 a32)))) - a31 (r1 - r2 a12 - r3 a13 + r3 a12 a23 + r2 a13 a32 - r1 a23 a32) (r3 (-1 + a12 a21) + r2 (-a12 a31 + a32) + r1 (a31 - a21 a32)) (-r3 a13^2 - r3 a12 a23^2 + r3 a13 (1 + a12 (a21 (-1 + a23) + a23)) + r2 a12 (a23 + a13 (-1 + a31 - a23 a31)) + r2 (-1 + a13) a13 a32 + r1 (a12 a23 (-a21 + a23 a31) - a13 (-1 + a31 - a21 a32 + a23 a32))) + a21 (r2 - r1 a21 + r3 a13 a21 - r3 a23 - r2 a13 a31 +  r1 a23 a31) (r3 (a13 - a12 a23) + r2 (a12 - a13 a32) + r1 (-1 + a23 a32)) (r3 (-a12^2 a23 + a12 (a13 + a23 + a13 a21 (-1 + a32)) - a13 a32) + r1 (a13 a32 (a31 - a21 a32) + a12 (-1 + a21 - a23 a31 + a23 a32)) + r2 (a12^2 + a13 a32^2 - a12 (1 + a13 (a31 (-1 + a32) + a32)))))/(1 - a12 a21 - a13 a31 + a12 a23 a31 + a13 a21 a32 - a23 a32)^3 < 0
];

r3 := 1 - r1 - r2;
reg = ImplicitRegion[ineq, {r1, r2}];

(* very slow *)
Clear[A]; \[Rho] = 0.5;
Plot[Area[reg], {A, 1, 8}, PlotPoints -> 5]
```

`Plot` apparently gets stuck on `A=1.00175`:

```
\[Rho] = 0.5; A = 1.00175;
Region[reg]
Area[reg]
(* 4.77927*10^10 - 8.56801*10^10 I *)
```

The weird thing is, it works fine if I use `p` instead of `\[Rho]`!

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a12 = p/A; a13 = A p;
a21 = A p; a23 = p/A;
a31 = p/A; a32 = A p;

ineq = as above...

r3 := 1 - r1 - r2;
reg = ImplicitRegion[ineq, {r1, r2}];

(* 13 sec *)
Clear[A]; p = 0.5;
Plot[Area[reg], {A, 1, 8}, PlotPoints -> 5]
```

[image]

What gives?!  I notice that the expressions from `Simplify` are in slightly different forms, but not very much.  I experience the same problem from `NIntegrate[1, {r1, r2} \[Element] reg]`.  How does `NIntegrate` work over regions?

```
$Version
(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)
```

**UPDATE (v13.3):**

Since v13.3, the version above that previously worked with `p` also fails, with `TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]`.

```
$Version
(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)
```

Comment: (+1) I also test another letter such as `t,s, w`, none of them work, besides `p`.

Comment: @cvgmt there is something magic about p ???

Comment: @chris Finally, I found that only for `m,n,o,p,q,r,...i,j,` work,but `t,s,w,... ` cann't work  :-)

Comment: @chris The ironic thing is I switched from `\[Rho]` to `p` when simplifying the problem for this site.  Next level rubber ducking!

Comment: Never use upper-case letters (e.g., `A`) to name a variable in *Mathematica* as it can conflict with the internal names of functions.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I like to live dangerously 